# online file storage that supports webdav with speedy read and writes

Tags: storage, webdav

I need online file storage that supports webdav so I can mount the storage as a drive to my local drive, priority is speedy read and writes, can you give me some recommendation?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own using IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .Net. You will just need to click-through [wizard in Viasual Studio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=BWbA9oXwl4Q). You will get the best performance if you select "store files and metadata in file system option".

Answer (score 0):

I have some of my SkyDrive folders mapped as local drives on my machine, and it works pretty well.  I have to admit that I haven't tested it for speed, so I'm not sure if it's up to the performance that you're looking for.

Some blogs to help you with the steps:

1. [Connect Your SkyDrive To  Windows Explorer](http://mynetx.net/2352/how-to-connect-your-skydrive-in-windows-explorer)
2. [Access SkyDrive from Windows Explorer through WebDAV](http://www.studentguru.gr/blogs/kingherc/archive/2010/01/01/access-skydrive-from-windows-explorer-through-webdav.aspx)
3. http://www.nirmaltv.com/2010/02/02/how-to-map-skydrive-as-network-drive-in-windows/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jackrabbit ( http://jackrabbit.apache.org/ ) will do what you want. It has a very simple standalone deployment option that you can just double-click and then access the file system via WebDAV.